# Unable to get Sheet names with GetOleSchemaTable()

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I am working with some code that uses an OleDbConnection to load data from an Excel file to a DataTable.  Currently it defaults to the first Sheet but getting it's name using the following code:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFilename.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""

DataTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
if (schemaTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    return schemaTable.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
else
    return "Sheet1$"
```

This has been working fine until recently when the Excel document (we are receiving from a third party) started containing named Ranges.  I'm there are no hidden sheets that I can find.

Now

```
schemaTable.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()
```

returns the name of the first Range.

Is there something different I can do with my schemaTable object to identity just the sheets and not the named Ranges in the sheet?

Comment: What do the other columns contain? When you output the complete contents of GetOleDbSchemaTable, do you notice any column that contains anything that allows you to differentiate between Ranges and Sheets? I could image that the `TABLE_TYPE` column could contain the required information. Here's a list of all the columns returned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.tables.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the use of OleDbConnection mandatory or you can switch to other options (DAO for instance) ?

alternative solution 1 : using interop :

```
    Private Function GetSheetNames(ByVal path As String)
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    'Note: this will not work for Excel 2007 (.xlsx) workbooks.
    If IO.File.Exists(path) AndAlso IO.Path.GetExtension(path) = ".xls" Then
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
    Try
       WB = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path)
       If WB IsNot Nothing Then
         For Each ws As Excel.Worksheet In WB.Sheets
           lst.Add(ws.Name)
         Next
         WB.Close()
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WB)
         WB = Nothing
       End If
    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app)
       app = Nothing
    End Try
     End If
     Return lst
End Function
```

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/21d3f77c-1d3d-44e0-9bd5-eca45a0affa6

Alternative solution 2 : using DAO :

```
Dim dao_dbE As dao.DBEngine
Dim dao_DB As dao.Database
dao_dbE = New dao.DBEngine
Dim sheetsNames As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
dao_DB = dao_dbE.OpenDatabase(completeFileName, False, True, "Excel 8.0;")
For i As Integer = 0 To dao_DB.TableDefs.Count - 1
    sheetsNames.Add(dao_DB.TableDefs(i).Name)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Heinzi correctly sad you should investigate other properties of returned metadata, it's the only way. Most probably ranges will be different from sheets by some property value.

**Update:**
Since this solution doesn't work, and if file is in XSLX format, I think fastest and simpliest solution is just to drill down to raw xml (remember XLSX is just ZIP) `myFilename.xlsx/xl/workbook.xml` using, say, [#ZipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) and grab all sheets names from `<sheets>` node.

Comment: Yes, I did try that but the only columns that contain non-null data are TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE (which is "TABLE" for all rows), DATE_CREATED and DATE_MODIFIED (which are all identical).  So I was unable to get any useful data from these.

Comment: That's a neat solution, I'll have a look a that.